# Auto populate field when creating the record

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have an object called Sortiment__c, which is related to Product object. When creating a new record on the Sortiment object I can choose the product I want as it is a lookup field.Now I want to autopopulate another field called sortiment_price with the price of the product I just chose. The field sortiment_price should immediately show the price(and not after saving the record) Is there any way to achieve this without using Apex? 
​​​​​​​Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this without Apex (and probably JavaScript); you'd need to build a custom user interface for record creation using a Lightning component or Visualforce page in order to achieve this. Otherwise, you'll have to settle for having the field populate at the time of saving, which you can do with Flow or simply by using a formula field.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here looks like it's something that can be addressed by the sf url hack(https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DKp3QAG)

Comment: While the link may be helpful, it also is a risk of being broken and leaving this answer with no information. It'd be best to [edit] your answer and provide details of the implementation referenced in the link.